# How do I effectively access list information in C++?

Tags: c++, list

I originally made this game in Python and then for a school project converted it over to C++.

The problem is that C++'s `std::list` does not allow me to access items like Python's `list` does (`list[1]`) and more so, accessing items of lists that are inside of a list (`list[2][5]`). I have not been able to find an effective way to be able to do this or an alternative to lists that will work.

Comment: Lists cannot be accessed by index. If you want random access, use vectors.

Comment: Do not confuse the term *list* when comparing C++ to Python.   A `std::list` is a doubly linked list in C++. meaning there is no random access to an element in the list.

Comment: Adding to @PaulMcKenzie, the most direct equivalent to a Python `list` is `std::vector` (they're both implemented as a single, dynamically sized array that performs overallocation to make insertion/removal at the end of the sequence amortized `O(1)`).

Comment: Related: [Python list equivalent in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17528657)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use a [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). It implements a *doubly linked list* which does not provide a subscript operator because random access for linked lists cannot be implemented with constant complexity.

Instead, use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which implements a *dynamically growing array* with subscript operator defined.

As [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) has commented, you might also find [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) useful. It supports constant time random access like `std::vector` but in addition has the ability to release storage automatically when you remove elements.  (For `std::vector`, you have to do it explicitly by calling `shrink_to_fit` and that can easily go the wrong direction.) It is also superior when you need to append elements both at the beginning and the end. But as I understand, you don't want to change the number of elements in the container anyway.

Also note another difference between Python and C++.  In Python, if you write

```py
my_things = [1, 2, 3, 4]
your_things = [5, 6, 7]
our_things = [my_things, your_things]
```

then `your_things` and `our_things[1]` refer to the same list. This is because objects in Python are referred to by-reference. In C++, on the other hand, containers have value semantics. That is, if you write

```
std::vector<int> my_things = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> your_things = {5, 6, 7};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> our_things = {my_things, your_things};
```

`our_things` will contain *copies* of `my_things` and `your_things` and changing either will not affect the other. If this is not what you want, you could instead define the nested list at once.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> our_things = {
  {1, 2, 3, 4},  // my things
  {5, 6, 7},     // your things
};
```

Comment: Or use `std::deque` if you need (effectively) constant time insertion/removal of elements at beginning and end (vs. vector's `O(n)` cost at the beginning, and amortized `O(1)` at the end, but with intermittent high cost for reallocation). `deque` still provides `O(1)` random access too, (the price paid is higher memory overhead and fragmentation thanks to being built from a bunch of small fixed size arrays, rather than `vector`'s single dynamically sized array). The only thing `deque` loses you is the ability to efficiently add and remove elements in the middle of the sequence while iterating.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `O` complexities are fine in theory, and if you've profiled your code to have a bottleneck, but `vector` should be the default sequential-access container. Because of caching, pre-fetching etc. Moder CPUs love coherent memory access.

Comment: I wouldn't consider `std::deque` unless I had some specific needs, like large number of inserts at the front. Even though it is constant time inserts, the constant is larger than for a vector. And the `O(1)` random access is more like `"O(2)"`, if we had such an animal.

Comment: @Angew: Agreed. As I said, use `std::deque` if you need `std:deque` features that `std::vector` doesn't provide; `std::vector` should be the "go to STL sequence". `std::deque` is useful when you need it, but it does have slightly higher overhead than `std::vector` for just about everything (it doesn't show up in the big-O times because the overhead is typically equivalent to a fixed multiplier, not related to the size of the sequence).  I should have clarified that the "only" loss in `std::deque` was relative to `std::list`; it has lots of small losses compared to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectors instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, std::list does not support random access lookup via operator []. If you are going to continue to use a list, you should look at the  std::advance function.

```
list<string>::iterator itr = whichList.begin();
std::advance(itr, i);
if (itr->empty())
{
 /* ... assuming that you're testing for an empty string */
}
```

If possible, you might want to consider other standard containers, such as std::vector or std::deque, both of which provide random access lookup via operator [].

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change the size of the list you could use plain array.

That might even be the fastest option. But `std::vector` is similar in performance as long as you don't change size.

Comment: Not “similar”: “identical”!